# git workflow: read access + pull request or write access?

Tags: git, productivity, github

Suppose there is a small team with 1 senior developer and 3 junior developers working on the same repo in a team on a github organization. The senior developer has admin access. What is the most common approach in the industry to setup the access for the junior developers?

Is it giving them read access only and ask them to submit a pull request every time they change something and it will be reviewed by the senior developer?

Or is it giving them full write access?

The goal here is to maximize productivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my organization, all developers, both junior and senior, submit pull requests that are reviewed by other developers.  Just because you are senior doesn't mean you can't make a mistake.

But we also don't limit write access to anyone.  We trust our people to not force push to master. (And worst case, the git server is backed up.)  Just because you are junior does not mean you are not responsible.

Rules are best enforced with culture, not technology.  The last thing you want in an emergency situation is someone trying to find the person with admin privileges.  If you don't trust them with your repo, you should not have hired them.